# Searching Binary Trees in Lisp

Tags: tree, common-lisp

I have been asked to create a function where the user specifies a target and a binary tree, the function will then return the path necessary to reach that node.

i.e the user will provide this (searchtree 'b '(((a . b). c).(d .((e . f). g)))) and the console will print left left right.

I have several problems.

My given understanding is that when working with trees in Lisp I must construct the tree using defun leaf, node, and then methods to retrieve the nodes and elements as well as methods to recognize whether it is a leaf or node before I begin constructing further functions to search the tree. But the way the problem was worded suggests I am over complicating my solution.

Could someone push me in the right direction as to what I should be doing, or suggest a resource to better understand the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you write "return", but then "print".  Which should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure you use in your example to represent a tree is a list constructed with `cons`:

```
? '(((a . b). c) . (d . ((e . f) . g)))
(((A . B) . C) D (E . F) . G)
```

which is the same as

```
? (cons (cons (cons 'a 'b) 'c) (cons 'd (cons (cons 'e 'f) 'g)))
(((A . B) . C) D (E . F) . G)
```

You could, however, use a different representation, for example structures constructed with `defstruct`. Therefore, it makes sense to create abstraction function to construct a tree, to extract left and right, and to test for nodes and leaves.

For a list, you could use:

```
(defun mktree (left right) (cons left right))
(defun nodep (tree) (consp tree))
(defun leafp (tree) (atom tree))
(defun left  (tree) (car tree))
(defun right (tree) (cdr tree))

? (mktree (mktree (mktree 'a 'b) 'c) (mktree 'd (mktree (mktree 'e 'f) 'g)))
(((A . B) . C) D (E . F) . G)
```

whereas for a structure the definitions would be as follows:

```
(defstruct (btree) left right)
(defun mktree (left right) (make-btree :left left :right right))
(defun nodep (tree) (btree-p tree))
(defun leafp (tree) (not (nodep tree)))
(defun left  (tree) (btree-left tree))
(defun right (tree) (btree-right tree))

? (mktree (mktree (mktree 'a 'b) 'c) (mktree 'd (mktree (mktree 'e 'f) 'g)))
#S(BTREE :LEFT #S(BTREE :LEFT #S(BTREE :LEFT A :RIGHT B) :RIGHT C) :RIGHT #S(BTREE :LEFT D :RIGHT #S(BTREE :LEFT #S(BTREE :LEFT E :RIGHT F) :RIGHT G)))
```

Either way, your `searchtree` function can be written in a way that is independent of your representation:

```
(defun searchtree (atm tree)
  (labels
      ((sub (tree res)
         (cond
          ((nodep tree) 
           (sub (left  tree) (cons 'left  res))
           (sub (right tree) (cons 'right res)))
          ((leafp tree)
           (when (eql atm tree)
             (return-from searchtree (reverse res)))))))
    (sub tree nil)))
```

so regardless on your representation you'd get

```
? (searchtree 'b (mktree (mktree (mktree 'a 'b) 'c) (mktree 'd (mktree (mktree 'e 'f) 'g))))
(LEFT LEFT RIGHT)
```

Comment: Thanksfor the help, could you talk me through the searchtree function?